# How to show the different layers on the different zoom level in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding, mapbox

I am now visualizing the polylines like below:

```
geojson = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lines, {

    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
        sliced: style},

        maxZoom: 24, // max zoom to preserve detail on
        interactive: true,
        getFeatureId: function(f) {
            return f.properties.id;
        }

}).on('mouseover', mouseover_function).addTo(map);
searchCtrl.indexFeatures(lines.features, ['id']);
info.addTo(map);
```

The lines are the geoJSON file of all the poly lines.Sow now I divided My lines into 3 parts of geoJSON and have

```
lines_1
lines_2
lines_3
```

So I create three layers with the above three layers

```
geojson1 = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lines1, {

        vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: style},

            maxZoom: 24, // max zoom to preserve detail on
            interactive: true,
            getFeatureId: function(f) {
                return f.properties.id;
            }

    }).on('mouseover', mouseover_function).addTo(map);


geojson2 = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lines2, {

        vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: style},

            maxZoom: 24, // max zoom to preserve detail on
            interactive: true,
            getFeatureId: function(f) {
                return f.properties.id;
            }

    })


geojson3 = L.vectorGrid.slicer(lines3, {

        vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: style},

            maxZoom: 24, // max zoom to preserve detail on
            interactive: true,
            getFeatureId: function(f) {
                return f.properties.id;
            }

    })
```

So this is the three layers and I want to show geojson1 at all levels of zoom and geojson2 in zoom level 20 and geojson3 at zoom level 22.

How can i show these layers on different zoom levels.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Related question (with answer) here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182652/12125